# Importing JSON data file into PostgreSQL using Python and Psycopg2

Tags: python, json, postgresql, psycopg2

I am having trouble getting my query to work. I have a JSON file with over 80k lines of data. Since I have been having so many problems I cut the document down to three lines just to see if I can get the data in before I attempt the full 80k lines:

```
Import psycopg2
import io
readTest1 = io.open("C:\Users\Samuel\Dropbox\Work\Python and Postgres\test1.json", encoding = "utf-8")
readAll = readTest1.readlines()
```

I have seen online that using readlines is not the best method but it is the only method i know. This method read the three lines in the file. I am not sure but I expected this to make it an array also.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = python_trial user = postgres")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test4 (data json);")
```

Create a table that only takes JSON data:

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO test4 VALUES (%s)", readAll)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO test4 VALUES (%s)", readAll)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I am not exactly sure what I am doing incorrectly. I am also seeing "\n" when i print (readAll). I think that is caused by using the readlines method and I am not sure if that is messing up my query also.

Comment: Check out the `json` library: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO test4 VALUES ('{0}')".format(readAll))
```

Or **(readAll,)**: 
    `cur.executemany("INSERT INTO test4 VALUES (%s)", (readAll,))`

See: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries