# How to create a new table in Postgresql from a .json file using Python and psycopg2?

Tags: sql, json, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am new to postgresql. I would like to insert information from .json and create a new table in Postgresql using python/psycopg2. I have looked over some StackOverflow posts and psychopg2 documentation without getting much further.
The closest question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667867/importing-json-data-file-into-postgresql-using-python-and-psycopg2), from which I derived the following:

The test .json file is as follows (which only has 1-level i.e. no nested .json structure):

```
[{"last_update": "2019-02-01"}]
```

Attempted python code:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import Json
from psycopg2 import Error
from unipath import Path
import io

def insert_into_table(json_data):
    try:
        with psycopg2.connect(  user = "thisuser",
                                password = "somePassword",
                                host = "127.0.0.654165",
                                port = '5455',
                                database = "SqlTesting") as conn:

            cursor = conn.cursor()
            read_json = io.open(data_path, encoding='utf-8')
            read_json_all = read_json.readlines()

            query = "INSERT INTO new_table VALUES (%s)"
            cursor.executemany(query, (read_json_all,))
            conn.commit()

            print("Json data import successful")

    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print("Failed json import: {}".format(error))

insert_into_table(data_path)
```

The above code didn't work regardless whether `new_table` didn't exist or if it was created manually as a place-holder.

Rather, it produced the following error message:

```
Failed json import: relation "new_table" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO new_table VALUES ('[{"last_update": "2019-02-01"...
```

During debugging, I saw:

```
for i in read_json:
    print (i)

# will result
# [{"last_update": "2019-02-01"}]
```

And

```
print (read_json_all)

# Will result
# ['[{"last_update": "2019-02-01"}]']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to use sqlalchemy to put your data into the postgres DB.  Below, I used a very simple json file, and created a Pandas DataFrame.  I then used sqlalchemy to place it into the DB.  Check the code here.  It should get you where you want to go.

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import json

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
with open('example_1.json') as data_file:    
    d = json.load(data_file)

def create_table():
   conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='SqlTesting' user='thisuser' password='somePassword' host='localhost' port='5432' ") 
   cur=conn.cursor() 
   cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_table (color TEXT, fruit TEXT, size TEXT)")  
   conn.commit() 
   conn.close() 

create_table()

df = json_normalize(d)

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://thisuser:somePassword@localhost:5432/SqlTesting")
df.to_sql("new_table", engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
print("Done")
```

Comment: Thank you, but the objective is to import json to postgresql in one step only, unless it is not possible.

Comment: I have read through more material, and it seems your solution is one of the more efficient ways to insert data, will accept as answer. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently, in `pandas v1.0.0`, `pandas.io.json.json_normalize` was deprecated and relocated to `pandas` namespace itself at `pandas.json_normalize`.  I haven't tested this, so I don't want to edit your answer, but I do know that it will not work as-is right now.  The correct import statement should be `from pandas import json_normalize`.